# Update values on one jsp on submitting other in struts2

Tags: struts2

Hi i have functionality in which two jsp there. result.jsp and data.jsp.
When click on button data.jsp open in popup window. i add data in that form and submit data. On submitting popup will close and want data total on result.jsp.

How can i update result.jsp on submitting data.jsp with updated value??

Comment: if you can refresh the main page, once you close the pop-up window fetch the fresh values using your action class

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in  javascript included  in your pop-up jsp as

**url** below is action you need to call after submitting the pop-up which generally is just a refresh to result.jsp(the action you used to view result.jsp)

```
//earlier code . now refresh the final page.
   window.opener.document.forms[0].action="url.action";
   window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();
 //more code
```